# Why doesn't iBooks save my place between the iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, books

**Background:** I finally bought a fiction book to read on my iOS devices. It's *Redshirts* by John Scalzi. I bought it from Apple. It was supposed to be DRM-free but wasn't. So the author got Macmillan to send a DRM-free version to anyone who sent a copy of their purchase confirmation. So I deleted the Apple Store version and replaced with the DRM-free epub file.

**Problem:** My understanding was that when I stop reading on the iPad I could later pick up the iPhone and have the book open up to the place where I stopped on the iPad. But this isn't happening. I've tried placing a bookmark when I finish reading but it doesn't change anything.

Is my original assumption incorrect?

Sync Bookmarks and Sync Collections are both on in iBooks settings on the iPad and iPhone.

I haven't migrated from MobileMe to iCloud yet (still waiting for Bare Bones to get Yojimbo to sync over iCloud). Is that a problem?

**Update**

I switched over to iCloud and syncing still doesn't happen. My guess is it's because I have two Apple IDs the one I use to make iTunes purchases is not the .mac Apple ID that became my iCloud account.

Comment: Sounds like a problem to me - my devices sync the way you described (syncs to iPhone when finished on the iPad without me doing anything). I suppose it could be a MobileMe/iCloud problem.

Comment: Mine sync correctly as well and I'm using iCloud, not mobileme. Note: I too use Yojimbo but I was so mad that the iOS version was read only I never got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iBooks uses your iTunes account to sync bookmarks and places.  My wife and I share an account for app and book purchases, so I setup a separate iCloud account for her thinking that her bookmarks would go there.  It turns out that I'm wrong, and it's the iTunes store account that stores it.  I wish iCloud was the storage location, since the other app settings and backups do work using separate accounts.

Comment: That sounds promising. Is there a way to associate my iPhone with my iTunes account? It's already associated with my iCloud account, but that's a different Apple ID than the one on my iTunes account.

Comment: Found it under Settings -> Store. I switched it from my iCould account to my iTunes store account. It works!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is an iCloud / mobile me issue. What you could do is set up a free iCloud account and then perhaps never use it if you do not want multiple accounts, but it would allow you to test it.

Comment: Thanks. Since the MobileMe sunset date is in three weeks I'll wait until then or a Yojimbo update, whichever is first.

Comment: Upgrading to iCloud doesn't disable MobileMe's iDisk component. You can keep using iDisk until the EOL date even after converting to iCloud.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mentioned that - you do not loose any off Mobile Me's functionality while the service is available.

Comment: That doesn't correlate with what Bare Bones told me. According to them, Yojimbo syncing will stop working if I switch to iCloud. I'm not willing to take that risk until July 1.

Comment: Then the additional iCloud account (apple ID) would be your best bet to trial it before then.

Answer (score 0):

If ever you have syncing problems, I find that turning sync off and back on solves the problem most times these days. I had this same problem (with an ePub file I purchased outside of Apple). All I did was open iBooks on my Mac (where I was having the syncing problem since I'd done reading on my iPhone but my place wasn't saved when I returned to my Mac) and hit the checkbox next to Sync, on the General tab.